# Getting the Error 'Not Found' when Mapping Routes

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes

When I try to Map a Route to a Api method call, I only get 'Not Found' in the index.html calling function. I've tried multiple routing template combinations but all get the same error, Not Found. Can anyone help with this?

## My Class

```
public class LogonController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Logon")]
    public Boolean Logon(string username, string password)
    {

        return true;
    }
 }
```

## My WebApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Logon",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{logon}/{username}/{password}",
        defaults: new
            {
                username = RouteParameter.Optional,
                password = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
      );
}
```

## My Index.html Caller

```
<div>
    <h2>All Products</h2>
    <ul id="logon" />
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Get User ID</h2>
    <input type="text" id="username" size="5" />
    <input type="text" id="password" size="5" />
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="find();" />
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var uri = 'api/logon';

    function formatItem(item) {
        return 'True';
    }

    function find() {
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
       // var email = $('#email').val();
       // var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
       // var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
        // $.getJSON(uri + '/' + username + ',' + password + ',' + email + ',' + firstname + ',' + lastname)
        $.getJSON(uri + '/' + username + ',' + password)
            .done(function (data) {
                $('#logon').text(formatItem(data));
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                $('#logon').text('Error: ' + err);
            });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem. I was going about everything the wrong way. First I was not returning an 'IEnumerable' object.
Next, there was no {action} attribute in my route mapping.
Finally, the request which was coming from an html file was not passing parameters. Here are the changes that were made.

## My Class

public class LogonController : ApiController
    {
        Logon[] log = new Logon[] 
        { 
            new Logon {  UserName = "Roland", Email = "mike@optonline.net", Password = "test" }, 
            new Logon {  UserName = "Yo-yo", Email = "mike@optonline.net", Password = "test" }, 
            new Logon {  UserName = "Hammer", Email = "mike@optonline.net", Password = "test" } 
        };

```
    [ActionName("LogonApi")]
    public IEnumerable<Logon> GetThisLogon(string username, string password)
    {

        var s = log.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.UserName == username);
        if (s == null)
        {
            return log;
        }
        return log;
    }


   [ActionName("LogonApi")]
    public IEnumerable<Logon> GetLogon()
    {

        return log;
    }
```

## The WebApiConfig

```
       config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "LogonApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{username}/{password}",
           defaults: new
           {
               username = RouteParameter.Optional,
               password = RouteParameter.Optional
           }
       );
```

## The JavaScript Call

```
<div>
    <h2>Get User ID</h2>
    <input type="text" id="username" size="5" />
    <input type="text" id="password" size="5" />
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="find();" />

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var uri = 'api/logon/LogonApi';


    function formatItem(item) {
        return 'True';
    }

    function find() {
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();

        $.getJSON(uri + '/', { username: username, password: password}) 
            .done(function (data) {
                $('#logon').text(formatItem(data));
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                $('#logon').text('Error: ' + err);
            });
    }
```

Comment: You should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/255183) your own answer.